# Deployment with Capistrano errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3, whenever-capistrano

I have deployed to a sandbox environment just fine, but when I go to deploy to a production. One that will be hosted across different servers. App server and Web server are on one, and a DB server is separate.

Im using Capistrano 3 and here is the error when I run `bundle exec cap production setup` i get this error - I removed the IP_address. Basic information. Separate DB, Separate Redis / Resque server, Separate workers... Im stumped...

```
[fd6d0d1d] Command: cd /var/www/gru/releases/20151113234954 && ( PATH=/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH RAILS_ENV=production ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    rake aborted!
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    TypeError: can't dup NilClass
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis.rb:30:in `dup'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis.rb:30:in `initialize'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/releases/20151113234954/config/initializers/resque_initialize.rb:4:in `new'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/releases/20151113234954/config/initializers/resque_initialize.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/releases/20151113234954/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    /var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    Tasks: TOP => environment
DEBUG [fd6d0d1d]    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as clduser@96.119.183.74: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: rake aborted!
TypeError: can't dup NilClass
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis.rb:30:in `dup'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis.rb:30:in `initialize'
/var/www/gru/releases/20151113234954/config/initializers/resque_initialize.rb:4:in `new'
/var/www/gru/releases/20151113234954/config/initializers/resque_initialize.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/var/www/gru/releases/20151113234954/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: rake aborted!
TypeError: can't dup NilClass
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis.rb:30:in `dup'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis.rb:30:in `initialize'
/var/www/gru/releases/20151113234954/config/initializers/resque_initialize.rb:4:in `new'
/var/www/gru/releases/20151113234954/config/initializers/resque_initialize.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/var/www/gru/releases/20151113234954/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as clduser@<REMOVED>.74: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: rake aborted!
TypeError: can't dup NilClass
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis.rb:30:in `dup'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis.rb:30:in `initialize'
/var/www/gru/releases/20151113234954/config/initializers/resque_initialize.rb:4:in `new'
/var/www/gru/releases/20151113234954/config/initializers/resque_initialize.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/var/www/gru/releases/20151113234954/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/var/www/gru/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake stderr: Nothing written
```

Comment: Looks like you're not able to SSH into your server as `clduser`. Get that working via command line SSH first then come back to capistrano.

Comment: Thanks. It actually works form the command line. I can SSH in just fine

Comment: Strange. Any special configs in `~/.ssh` ?

Comment: Thanks for the assist, but it turned out there were some special ssh hash that I needed to pass into the deploy.rb script.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: and now I have a new error

Comment: How were you ever able to fix this @R.J.Robinson? I'm bumping into the same issue.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there was some resque plugin gem that caused this.  It was a long time ago, sorry